# File Input Java Mac

Tags: java, macos, file-io

I'm writing up a program that goes into a basic .txt file and prints certain things. It is a comma-delimited file. The file includes 7 first and last names, and also 4 numbers after. Each of the seven on a separate line.

Each line looks like this:

> George Washington, 7, 15, 20, 14

The program has to grab the last name and then average the 4 numbers, but also average the first from all seven, second from all seven, etc. I'm not sure on how to start approaching this and get it to keep grabbing and printing what's necessary. Thanks for any help. I appreciate it. I'm using a Mac to do all of this programming and it needs to run on Windows so I'm using :

```
File Grades = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "grades.txt");
```

so how would I use that to read from the file?

Comment: Haven't you already opened two other questions on this same issue?

Comment: They were two different issues with the input that I was having. This is a new issue.

Comment: Firstly, your question titles are so similar that it would be easy to think the questions are the same; please use titles which are more descriptive.  Secondly, in using Java, it shouldn't matter much that you are using a Mac if you do things right.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Sorry. I'll remember that next time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't worry about whether it's running on Mac or Windows. Java takes care of all the business for you. :)

You could do something like the following. It's just a quick solution so you might want to do some changes perhaps. It reads from a file named "input.txt" right now.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ParseLines {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
      BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(fs)));

      String line;
      double collect[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
      int lines = 0;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        if (parts.length == 5) {
          int avg = 0;
          boolean skip = false;
          for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            String part = parts[i].trim();

            try {
              int num = Integer.valueOf(part);
              avg += num;
              collect[i - 1] += (double) num;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nexp) {
              System.err.println("Input '" + part +
                                 "' not a number on line: " + line);
              skip = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (skip) continue;

          avg /= 4;
          lines++;                    

          System.out.println("Last name: " + parts[0].split(" ")[1] +
                           ", Avg.: " + avg);
        }
        else {
          System.err.println("Ignored line: " + line);
        }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        collect[i] /= (double) lines;
        System.out.println("Average of column " + (i + 1) + ": " +
                           collect[i]);
      }

      reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }    
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Altered the code to average the first, second, third and fourth column.

Comment: This helps a lot by giving me something to go from. But how would I get it to take the first score from all 7 and average it, the second from all 7 and average it, and so forth for all four. And then carry them out to a farther decimal point?

Comment: No problem. You could store the information in an array, for instance, and then update it as you go. When all the lines have been read and processed you can compute the all the averages.

Comment: I'm just not sure on how I would do that. Would I need to have an array for each one? I'm really confused by all of this and I'm just trying to get a good handle on what it looks like so I can learn it.

Comment: @Mary: I edited the code to do what you wanted. :) `collect` collects all the additions and in the end it divides by the number of lines it read and prints out the results.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is perfect. Now I can understand what I'm supposed to be doing. I appreciate the help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Java's [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class doesn't actually handle the opening or reading for you.  You may want to look at the [FileReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) classes.

Comment: I just got it going from the file class into a BufferedReader class, but it's saying I can't do a readLine() for some reason. Error saying it cannot find symbol.

Comment: @Marry:  I'd need to see some code to figure out why you couldn't get readLine() to work, but since you accepted the other answer, I assume that guided you to where you could get your code to work.

Comment: I figured it out. I was mixed up with a few things before the readLine() but I figured it out.